# How to draw paths using SVG?

Tags: jquery, html, svg, raphael

I'm wanting to animate the cursive text below, from left to right.[image]

An example of want i'm trying to acheive can be found on the slaveryfootprint.org site.
Select an electronic item in the link below, and watch the cables animate; 
http://slaveryfootprint.org/survey/#gadgets

I'm unfamiliar with SVG and SVG libraries like Raphaël js, so i'm not sure where to start.
I've googled around, but not found a tutorial.

**EDIT**: Find the first  tag below, saved from illustrator, depicting the `d` first character:

```
<g>
<path fill="none" stroke="#8C3939" stroke-linecap="round" d="M216.615,297.73c9.509,10.697,24.563-12.282,18.444-15.658
    c-6.074-3.351-10.125,5.753-10.125,5.753s-4.297,8.542,2.08,13.137c8.42,6.673,15.817-3.188,15.947-3.43"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the path, you can do almost anything.  Another alternative would be to hand the path to an incremental path expander in javascript.  Here's the code I typically use (I've posted it as part of other answers and it's not entirely unique, but this incarnation is mine):

```
function drawpath( canvas, pathstr, duration, attr, callback )
{
    var guide_path;
    if ( typeof( pathstr ) == "string" )
        guide_path = canvas.path( pathstr ).attr( { stroke: "none", fill: "none" } );
    else
        guide_path = pathstr;
    var path = canvas.path( guide_path.getSubpath( 0, 1 ) ).attr( attr );
    var total_length = guide_path.getTotalLength( guide_path );
    var last_point = guide_path.getPointAtLength( 0 );
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var interval_length = 50;
    var result = path;        

    var interval_id = setInterval( function()
    {
        var elapsed_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
        var this_length = elapsed_time / duration * total_length;
        var subpathstr = guide_path.getSubpath( 0, this_length );            
        attr.path = subpathstr;

        path.animate( attr, interval_length );
        if ( elapsed_time >= duration )
        {
             clearInterval( interval_id );
             if ( callback != undefined ) callback();
             guide_path.remove();
        }                                       
    }, interval_length );  
    return result;
}
```

You'd then feed in the path for your text to this function.  Ideally, I'd do it one letter at a time -- complicated paths seem to get bogged down in Firefox, though Chrome seems to deal with them just fine.

Here's a [mock-up](http://voidblossom.com/tests/cursive.php) on my site.

Comment: many thanks Kevin! http://jsfiddle.net/PEneM/1/  heres how i'm going to implement your drawpath function.

Comment: i have noticed that sometimes it draws the path, and other times it scales the path. it only started scaling when i started using a setTimeout delay rather than  a cb function

Comment: I've also noticed that -- especially in Firefox.  I believe it might be Raphael's response when a detailed path transformation consumes enough calculation time that the animation timer falls behind.  You might get some mileage out of 1) animating the phrase in segments so that the actively animated path is less complex, or 2) dropping the interval in drawpath lower (or both).  Are you dev'ing in Firefox or Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

If you make the cursive text as one stroke you can easily animate it with a stroke-dashoffset + stroke-dasharray attribute. An example of this technique can be seen [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/smil/pen-stroke-animation.svg).

The solution is to set a dasharray for the path, with one dash that is the same length as the path, and one dash-gap which is also the same length as the path (this length is easily found at runtime by calling the `getTotalLength()` method on the path element). Then you can push the dash around by animating the `stroke-dashoffset` attribute.

The technique should be possible to apply with raphaël and other svg frameworks too. Note that the [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/smil/pen-stroke-animation.svg) shows svg animation with the values predetermined.

Comment: Thanks Erik! i've been playin with the co-ordinates 'saved as SVG' from illustrator. Do you know if theres an other way to automate this  process.

Comment: You'd have to be more specific about what that automation should do.

Comment: hey Erik, i'm looking to translate the SVG information that illustrator exports into a something a framework like raphaël can understand and animate. When i paste the information into the example you supplied it ceases to animate, i know it'll take tweaking, maybe registration and scale are out? I'll add the info for the cursive text above.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point: [How to work with Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) in HTML 5](http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-scalable-vector-graphics-svg-in-html-5/25183)